# How I can convert model.pt to model.h5?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

After using YOLOv5 to train model weights as .pt file,
how can I convert the weights file (model.pt) to hdf5 file (model.h5)?

Running `python train.py --batch 16 --epochs 3 --data mydata.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt`, the result is given by `best.pt` file at subfolder of YOLOv5, how can I convert it to h5 file?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can answer your question better. Thanks!

Comment: Use `model = torch.hub.load('c:\yolov5', 'custom', path=r"C:\path\to\pt\best.pt", source='local')` for loading model, then use `torch.save(model, './path/myfile.hdf5')` for saving hdf5 file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do [this](https://github.com/gmalivenko/pytorch2keras#installation) installation and get started [here](https://github.com/gmalivenko/pytorch2keras)

This could be a lengthy procedure ...    as you are aware that .pt only contains weights and not model architecture hence your model class should also be present in  your conversion code

Edit: New links are added

Comment: Links no longer exists, please update this answer.

Comment: Link is unavailable, please mention the package name in your answer instead of amorphic links.

Comment: https://github.com/gmalivenko/pytorch2keras is the link which is not working in above answer